# Is it possible to display InfoWindow not under google controls (stree, pan, zoom etc..)

Tags: google-maps

I tried to change zIndex but sounds like it is impossible. Also tried to use InfoBox control but it still show incorrectly...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification

http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_controls_disable

Second link shows how to do it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
   function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
zoom:7,
disableDefaultUI:true,    
panControl: true, 
mapTypeControl: true, 
scaleControl: true, 
streetViewControl: true, 
overviewMapControl: true, 
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the link which you shown doesn't display any popops and any controls

Comment: Hey Sergey, I added where you can disable the default ui andthen you just add back what you want.  That work?

Comment: Hi Jesse, no, the question is how to display the controls behind the InfoWindow

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is some other hack. You do not use the info window of google maps but create your own. Create a div and addListener for click event on maps. On click find x and y location of event and set div's top and left according to that. I you need more help on this, comment.

Also you can try overlays: http://codepen.io/emgerold/pen/kjivC `function InfoBox(opts)`